# Multiline AggregateItemReader not working as suggested in spring-batch-samples

Tags: spring, spring-batch, multiline

I am trying to use the multiline IteamReader following the spring-batch-sample at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/main/spring-batch-samples#multiline

I am running into compilation error as below -

[image]

I am sure there is something related to generics as it looking for class implementing ItemReader but the AggregateItemReader implements ItemReader<List>.

```
public class AggregateItemReader<T> implements ItemReader<List<T>> {
```

you can find my code here - https://github.com/arpit9mittal/spring-batch-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/my/demo/batch/BatchConfiguration.java

UPDATE:

I suppressed the generics and updated the AggregateItemReader as below inorder to call ItemStreamReader open() method.

```
public class AggregateItemReader<T> implements ItemStreamReader<List<T>> {
private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(AggregateItemReader.class);

private ItemStreamReader<AggregateItem<T>> itemReader;
```

I noticed that the ItemWriter is writing lists of record instead of record per line

```
[Trade: [isin=UK21341EAH45,quantity=978,price=98.34,customer=customer1], Trade: [isin=UK21341EAH46,quantity=112,price=18.12,customer=customer2]]
[Trade: [isin=UK21341EAH47,quantity=245,price=12.78,customer=customer3], Trade: [isin=UK21341EAH48,quantity=108,price=9.25,customer=customer4], Trade: [isin=UK21341EAH49,quantity=854,price=23.39,customer=customer5]]
[Trade: [isin=UK21341EAH47,quantity=245,price=12.78,customer=customer6], Trade: [isin=UK21341EAH48,quantity=108,price=9.25,customer=customer7], Trade: [isin=UK21341EAH49,quantity=854,price=23.39,customer=customer8]]
```

AND When i try to add a processor, it complains that processor cannot convert the list into Trade object.

```
@Bean
public ItemProcessor<Trade, Trade> processor() {
    return new ItemProcessor<Trade, Trade>() {

        @Override
        public Trade process(Trade item) throws Exception {
            item.setProcessed(true);
            return item;
        }
    };
}

@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
@Bean
public Step multilineStep(
        AggregateItemReader reader, 
        ItemProcessor processor,
        FlatFileItemWriter writer,
        StepItemReadListener itemReadListener) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("multiLineStep")
            .chunk(1)
            .reader(reader)
            .writer(writer)
            .processor(processor)
            .build();
}
```

ERROR:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to my.demo.batch.multiline.Trade
    at my.demo.batch.BatchConfiguration$2.process(BatchConfiguration.java:1) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doProcess(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:134) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.transform(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:319) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:210) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:77) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
```

HELP:

1. How can we make it work without suppressing generics ?
2. How to ensure that ItemReader returns list just the same way as it does with chunk processing, so that ItemProcessor and ItemWriter works as usual ?
3. Is it possible to do so without extending the SimpleStepBuilder & SimpleChunkProvider ?

Comment: @Dave Syer please guide on what/where I have incorrectly used you multiline sample

Comment: The sample you are referring to is configured in xml where the generic type info is not checked at configuration time. Have you tried to omit the generics in your Java config? Something like `@Bean public Step multilineStep(AggregateItemReader reader,StepItemReadListener itemReadListener,  FlatFileItemWriter writer) {
 return stepBuilderFactory.get("multiLineStep")
.chunk(1)...`

Comment: It worked after changing the AggregateItemReader<T> implements ItemStreamReader instead of AggregateItemReader<T> implements ItemReader because I need to call the open() method of the delegate FlatItemReader... Now, I do not want the generics to be suppressed and the output file should have Trade object per line instead of list of trade objects per line. Any ideas how to fix this ?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine how can we make step to treat list of reads similar to list it creates when you have chunk size of more than 1. If we can do that then Processor and Writer will work as normal instead of consuming lists of list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be consistent in what the type of the items is that you want to handle on batch level. According to your step definition it is `Trade`. By calling `<Trade, Trade>chunk(1)` on the step builder, you declare that your batch should read items of type `Trade` with a chunk size of 1 (i.e. one at a time) and pass these on to a writer for items of type `Trade`. In this case, you need to supply a reader of type `ItemReader<Trade>`, a writer of type `ItemWriter<Trade>` and optionally a processor of type `ItemProcessor<Trade, Trade>`.

The problem is that your reader is of type `ItemReader<List<Trade>>`, i.e. it does not yield a `Trade` for each invocation of its `read` method but a **list** of trades.

If you want to use the `AggregateItemReader` you need to wrap it into a custom reader that works as an adapter and actually returns `Trade` items and not `List<Trade>`.

For example, the custom `read` method could look like this:

```
public Trade read() throws Exception {
    if (queue.isEmpty()) {
        List<Trade> trades = aggregateItemReader.read();
        if (trades != null) {
            queue.addAll(trades);
        }
    }
    return queue.poll();
}
```

with `queue` initialized as

```
private Deque<Trade> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();
```

Comment: I am unable to picture your solution. Can you show me with an example?

Comment: I exchanged the high-level description with a code example.

Comment: Basically now it becomes read from memory instead of file. Now I have to manage the chunk size smartly. Smart thinking. Appreciate your help. Enjoy the bounty :)

Comment: Based on the above suggestion, the problem is resolved. One can refer to code here - https://github.com/arpit9mittal/spring-batch-demo